# What is wrong with my NMinimize code?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I don't know how to write the code to find `Mu1` and `Mu2`. Can you help me  Please?.

This is what I tried.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Please do not post images of your work. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't post the Mathematical code because I don't know to make easier posted here. I'm newbie :(
But maybe you can download this file here : [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BtDzvN8FA190BFKj5pjd1C58BGUQlujm/view?usp=sharing)

@m_goldberg

Comment: Maybe you should start with a simple Minimization problem, get that working, and then slowly make it more complex. For example, you are missing a comma after the {mu1, mu2} term.

Comment: You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful for formatting code.

Comment: The error message `{Method mu1, Method mu2} -> NelderMead is not a valid variable` is showing you that it is multiplying `{mu1, mu2}` and `Method -> "NelderMead"` together. Make sure to add a comma after the `}` and before `Method`. I don't know if that will make the code work, but it's one problem that I see.

Comment: Hehehe thanks @bills I've tried that, but for this problem maybe i don't read my work carefully

Comment: thank youu @MichaelE2

Comment: yeah that's true :) I forget to add comma, but with them the solution is same with my post above. There isn't any number that show for Mu1 and Mu2. Just show (Mu1,Mu2) @MassDefect

Answer (score 3):

```
K11=30;K12=20;K22=10;m1=8;m2=20;δ1=1;δ2=0.5;θ1=1;θ2=0.4;
a=0.5;b=0.5;λ=0.05;α=10;β=3;P=500;d=300;CR=4;S=100;r=0.2;
H=5;CA=30;Q=131;σ1=Sqrt[a];σ2=Sqrt[b];

NMinimize[{(d/Q(K11(a+(μ1-m1)^2)+K22(b(μ2-m2)^2)+K12((μ1-m1)*
(μ2-m2)))Q/P+(K11 a+K22 b)((Q/P)^2/2-(Q/P)/λ+(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/
λ^2)+((K11(2(μ1-m1)δ1)+K22(2(μ2-m2)δ2)+K12((μ1-m1)δ2+(μ2-m2)δ1))+
(K11 δ1^2+K22 δ2^2+K12 δ1 δ2))(Q/P-(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ)+
((K11(2(μ1-m1)θ1)+K22(2(μ2-m2)θ2)+K12((μ1-m1)θ2+(μ2-m2)θ1))+
(K11(2 δ1 θ1)+K22(2 δ2 θ2)+K22(δ1 θ2+δ2 θ1)))(0.5(Q/P)^2-
(Q/P)/λ+(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ^2)+(K11 θ1^2+K22 θ2^2+K12 θ1 θ2)*
((Q/P)^3/3-(Q/P)^2/λ+2(Q/P)/λ^2+2(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ^3))+(d/Q*
CR((μ1+δ1)Q/P-δ1(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ+θ1(0.5(Q/P)^2-(Q/P)/λ+
(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ^2))+CR((μ2+δ2)Q/P-δ2(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ+θ2*
(0.5(Q/P)^2-(Q/P)/λ+(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ^2)))+(S d/Q)+(r*CR*
((μ1+δ1)Q/P-δ1(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ+δ1(0.5(Q/P)^2-(Q/P)/λ+
(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ^2))+CR((μ2+δ2)Q/P-δ2(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ+θ2*
(0.5(Q/P)^2-(Q/P)/λ+(1-Exp[-λ Q/P])/λ^2))d/Q)+(d/Q CA)+
(d/Q(α Q/P+0.5 β(Q/P)^2)),
m1-4 σ1<μ1<m1+4 σ1&&m2-4 σ2<μ2<m2+4 σ2},{μ1,μ2},Method->"NelderMead"]
```

almost instantly returns

```
{16893.179829995734, {μ1 -> 8.355626751067383, μ2 -> 18.704839508932128}}
```

EDIT

Several errors in my translation found and fixed. The result is much closer, but still not exactly the same, as what the author found.

Please check all this very carefully, character by character, to try to understand why I made each change and to make certain that I have made no mistakes. I expect that additional errors remain.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bill that's helpful. But in the paper that I review show the result Mu1 = 8 and Mu2 = 19.34

Comment: Woww, Thank you so much @Bill it works when I tried again with your code. And sorry for my slow respond because I can't open my PC since 3 days before. Once again thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry @Bill, maybe I need your help again with the same question about this function. There is some revision with the function, but I tried again with your answer it doesn't work well. Maybe you can see my newest quoestion about the revision of my function. Thanks